# Statistics on Location Settings vs. Power Consumption

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, cllocationmanager, power-management

Is there any data on how `GPS` power consumption changes with different `CLLocationManager` settings, such as desired accuracy and distance filter? How it changes between different `iPhone` models? How it differs by location?

For my social location-aware app, more accuracy is always better, but no specific amount is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the section "**Tips for Conserving Battery Power**" in documentation. In particular this part:

> Use lower-resolution values for the desired accuracy unless doing so
>   would impair your app. Requesting a higher accuracy than you need
>   causes Core Location to power up additional hardware and waste power
>   for precision you are not using. Unless your app really needs to know
>   the user’s position within a few meters, do not put the values
>   kCLLocationAccuracyBest or kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters in the
>   desiredAccuracy property. And remember that specifying a value of
>   kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers does not prevent the location
>   service from returning better data. Most of the time, Core Location
>   can return location data with an accuracy within a hundred meters or
>   so using Wi-FI and cellular signals.

source: [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

Comment: That's helpful, but what I really need (and anyone else who needs to balance accuracy and power) are *hard* numbers. What's the % difference even between maximum GPS power and no GPS power?